# Magento 2 Luma theme menu/navigation

Tags: magento2

I've spun up a VM with Magento 2 install with sample data deployed and using the Luma theme. The navigation at the top of the theme had links to all the categories with sample data. I removed the sample data, created my own categories and added products. I cannot work out how to get my new categories into the menu or edit the menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this. My categories were not children of the default category.